# An extension that is not normal

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I have the following problem:

Let $F = \mathbb{F}_{p}(s,t)$ where $p$ is prime. Assume that $\beta$ is a root of $x^{2} - sx + t \in F[x]$ and $\alpha$ a root of $x^{p} - \beta$ (in some algebraic closure of $F$). If $K = F(\alpha)$, is it true that $K$ is not a normal extension of $F$?

I am proceeding by contradiction, i.e., $K$ is a normal extension of $F$. Since $\beta$ is a root of $x^{2} - sx + t$, then

\begin{equation}
\beta = \frac{s \pm \sqrt{s^{2}-4t}}{2}.
\end{equation}

If $\gamma$ is the other root of the polynomial, we have that $\beta + \gamma = s$. Then, since $\alpha^{p} = \beta$ and $\beta^{2} = s\beta - t$, we have

\begin{equation}
\alpha^{2p} = \beta^{2} = s\beta - t = s\alpha^{p} - t.
\end{equation}

Therefore, $\alpha$ is a root of $x^{2p} - sx^{p} + t \in F[x]$.

These are the ideas I have, but I don't know if they help me solve the problem. Any help or advice?

Comment: Careful, $p=2$ is possible so that construction of $\beta$ could be invalid

Comment: Does it make sense to define $F(\alpha)$ in terms of $x^p-\beta$ when $\beta$ is not in $F$? $F(\alpha)$ is, in my studies, taken to be $F[x]/(x^p-\beta)$ but that doesn't work as $\beta\notin F$ in general